MIDI piano connection on Ubuntu
I have a Roland FP-10 piano. I've connected it via bluetooth to my machine. I'm using LMMS to test it. I can see several options for devices when I select the ALSA-Sequencer driver, one of which is labeled "128:0 FP-10:FP-10 bluetooth", however when I select this device and press on keys, nothing happens. It's as if I have never pressed any keys on the keyboard.
I did some tinkering with suggestions from older videos/questions (from around the early 2010s) mainly focused around Jack Audio, but those ended up breaking all of the audio on my laptop and I had to wipe my whole laptop and restore it from a backup.
Ubuntu details:
$ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="24.04"
VERSION="24.04.1 LTS (Noble Numbat)"
VERSION_CODENAME=noble
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=noble
LOGO=ubuntu-logo

Results of pipewire --version:
$ pipewire --version
pipewire
Compiled with libpipewire 1.0.5
Linked with libpipewire 1.0.5

I'm certain my setup is using pipewire, and I've tried installing pipewire-jack and testing with midisnoop. midisnoop sees the device similar to lmms, but doesn't show any events when any key is hit. After installing pipewire-jack I tried running it again with pw-jack midisnoop and while I was able to select the device with the jack driver in midisnoop again there was no output.
I also recompiled bluez with midi support and installed that, but I see no difference. I suspect midi support may have already been available on my system though I'm not sure how to check.

@guiverc I've added system details and some subsequent debugging steps I've attempted now. Sorry I missed that before!
